# Angular 2 .Replace Pipe

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've created a replace pipe as follows:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    let newValue = value.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    return `${newValue}`;
  }
}
```

I declared it in @NgModule section of app.module. I am using it on the page as follows:

```
<ion-card-content [innerHtml]="Message | linky | replace"></ion-card-content>
```

I can't figure out where I am making the mistake because I can't get it to work. I tried removing linky pipe but no luck. Any help is much appriciated. Thanks Guys

Comment: When you say you can't get it to work, what do you mean? What kind of error or problem are you running into?

Comment: Not getting any errors what so ever

Comment: why are you trying to replace `<,>` and using the result at `innerHtml`, this doesn't make any sense. refer this https://plnkr.co/edit/dJDgLgmyhtaEYjCtpA8Y?p=preview

Comment: You have exactly the same code as me and I don't get why it is working you and not me. I copied and pasted my code there as well and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So It turns out my replace pipe works with everything example "`value.replace('bit', '<br>');`" but whatever I try to do It doesn't not work for "`value.replace('/\n/g', '<br>');`" Any Ideas?